# update a column based on whether another column was updated

Tags: oracle11g

I have two columns in the table -

Column_1

last_update_date

So when column_1 is updated, I need to update last_update_date. How should I write my update query? I'm using oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
update table_name
   set Column_1 = 'column_1_value', 
       last_update_date = sysdate
```